# How to define Faker Price,Address, Image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a DB where 3 fields are there.

```
1.TransectionDate
2.Price
3.Description
4.Image
5.CompanyName
```

My code is

```
$factory->define(Cost::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'TransectionDate' => $faker->date,
        'Amount' => $faker->????,
        'Description' => $faker->????,
        'Images' => $faker-> ????,
        'CompanyName' => $faker->company
    ];
});
```

What I will write instead ???? mark

Comment: have you tried checking out the manual? https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker, the library has faker for images, description (text), and amount (price)

Answer (score 12):

you can do it like below

```
$factory->define(Cost::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'TransectionDate' => $faker->date,
    'Amount' => $faker->randomDigit,
    'Description' => $faker->paragraph,
    'Images' => $faker->imageUrl($width = 200, $height = 200),
    'CompanyName' => $faker->company
 ];
});
```

you can also use number between for amount like

```
'Amount' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1500, $max = 6000)
```

Comment: Do you have api reference for this one?